# две таблицы tableview javafx drag and drop

Tags: javafx, tableview, drag-n-drop

Привет всем!
Проект на javafx springboot.

Сделал две таблицы одна смотрит в базу данных, вторая динамическая для отобранных из базы сущностей. Drag and drop-ом надо перекидывать выбираемые сущности из первой таблицы (база данных) во вторую динамическую. И потом работать с ними. Кто ни будь сталкивался с подобными заданиями?
Почти все сделал, но динамическая таблица отображает данные в геометрической прогрессии при выборе 1 строки отображает 2 строки и на увеличение.
Динамическая таблица (здесь map-лю Сущность из базы в объект для динамической таблицы):

```
private ObservableList<House> getHouseList(HousePrimaryRights housePrimaryRights)  {
        List<House> newHouses = new ArrayList<>();
        housesAllDinList = FXCollections.observableArrayList(newHouses);
        tableViewHouseUpdata = new TableView<>(housesAllDinList);
        if (housePrimaryRights != null) {
            IMergingContext context = new MergingContext();
            House house = context.map(housePrimaryRights, House.class);
            newHouses.add(house);

        } else tableViewHouseUpdata.getItems().clear();


        return housesAllDinList;
```

Здесь отрабатываю захвать нужной строки в таблице из базы данных

```
tableViewHouseData.setOnMouseClicked(event -> {
            if (event.getClickCount() == 1) {
                tableViewHouseData.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(
                        (observable, oldValue, newValue) -> showHouseDetails(newValue));
                buttonAdd.fire();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Простой пример одностороннего dragAndDrop'a (в остальном почитайте про методы со словом drag):

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.input.ClipboardContent;
import javafx.scene.input.DataFormat;
import javafx.scene.input.Dragboard;
import javafx.scene.input.TransferMode;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        // Таблица источник
        TableView<MyEntity> tableView1 = new TableView<>();

        TableColumn<MyEntity, Long> columnId1 = new TableColumn<>("Id");
        columnId1.setCellValueFactory(param -> new SimpleObjectProperty<>(param.getValue().id));

        TableColumn<MyEntity, String> columnName1 = new TableColumn<>("Name");
        columnName1.setCellValueFactory(param -> new SimpleObjectProperty<>(param.getValue().name));

        // Начало пертаскивания
        tableView1.setOnDragDetected(event -> {
            TableView<MyEntity> tableView = (TableView) event.getSource();
            MyEntity selectedItem = tableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
            if ( selectedItem != null ) {
                ClipboardContent content = new ClipboardContent();
                content.put(MyEntity.CLIPBOARD_DATA_FORMAT, selectedItem);

                tableView.startDragAndDrop(TransferMode.ANY).setContent(content);
            }
            event.consume();
        });
        tableView1.getColumns().addAll(columnId1, columnName1);

        tableView1.getItems().addAll(
                new MyEntity(1L, "One"),
                new MyEntity(2L, "Two"),
                new MyEntity(3L, "Three")
        );

        // Таблица приемник
        TableView<MyEntity> tableView2 = new TableView<>();

        TableColumn<MyEntity, Long> columnId2 = new TableColumn<>("Id");
        columnId2.setCellValueFactory(param -> new SimpleObjectProperty<>(param.getValue().id));

        TableColumn<MyEntity, String> columnName2 = new TableColumn<>("Name");
        columnName2.setCellValueFactory(param -> new SimpleObjectProperty<>(param.getValue().name));

        // Перетаскиваем с зажатой мышкой (до бросания)
        tableView2.setOnDragOver(event -> {
            if (event.getGestureSource() != event.getSource() && event.getDragboard().hasContent(MyEntity.CLIPBOARD_DATA_FORMAT) ) {
                event.acceptTransferModes(TransferMode.COPY_OR_MOVE);
            }
            event.consume();
        });
        // Бросание объекта
        tableView2.setOnDragDropped(event -> {
            TableView tableView = (TableView) event.getSource();
            Dragboard db = event.getDragboard();
            boolean completed = false;
            if ( db.hasContent(MyEntity.CLIPBOARD_DATA_FORMAT) ) {
                MyEntity content = (MyEntity) db.getContent(MyEntity.CLIPBOARD_DATA_FORMAT);
                tableView.getItems().add(content);
                completed = true;
            }
            // Это для случая, если будет добавлена обработка dragDone на первой таблице
            event.setDropCompleted(completed);
            event.consume();
        });
        tableView2.getColumns().addAll(columnId2, columnName2);

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(new HBox(tableView1, tableView2), 300, 300));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    // Сущность базы данных
    static class MyEntity implements Serializable {

        static DataFormat CLIPBOARD_DATA_FORMAT = new DataFormat(MyEntity.class.getName());

        MyEntity(Long id, String name) {
            this.id = id;
            this.name = name;
        }

        Long id;

        String name;

    }

}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое то что надо :)